# postgres: Error querying database

Tags: postgresql

Project run for some time after the database connection is not found, the error message is as follows：

2017-05-02 10:02:17,224 ERROR [main] (line:com.unis.license.agent.management.aop.ManagementServicesAop.afterThrowing(ManagementServicesAop.java:47)) - BeforeMethod:com.unis.license.agent.management.service.impl.LicenseServiceImpl.loadLicenseInfo       Params: []
2017-05-02 10:02:17,225 ERROR [main] (line:com.unis.license.agent.management.aop.ManagementServicesAop.afterThrowing(ManagementServicesAop.java:50)) - methodException:com.unis.license.agent.management.service.impl.LicenseServiceImpl.loadLicenseInfo  Exception:org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException:

#### Error querying database.  Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: the database system is starting up)

#### The error may exist in licenseAgent/orm/LicenseInfo.xml

#### The error may involve com.unis.license.agent.management.dao.ILicenseInfoOper.getAll

#### The error occurred while executing a query

#### Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: the database system is starting up)

2017-05-02 10:02:17,226 ERROR [main] (line:org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:318)) - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.unis.license.agent.management.filter.Initialization#0' defined in class path resource [spring-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.NoTransactionException: No transaction aspect-managed TransactionStatus in scope
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:381)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:293)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:799)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:446)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:791)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:296)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1347)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:743)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:492)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:99)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:154)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)

My DataSource configuration information is as follows：

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"></property>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/ucsm"></property> 
    <property name="username" value="uqdm"></property>
    <property name="password" value="unis123"></property>
    <property name="maxActive" value="100"></property>
    <property name="maxIdle" value="30"></property>
    <property name="maxWait" value="500"></property>
    <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="true"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:licenseAgent/mybatiscfg.xml"></property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean> 
<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
    <property name="basePackage" value="com.unis.license.agent.management.dao" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Although the error database is abnormal, but after the restart the project just fine。

Comment: Most liekly your postgres config does not fix. Did you check pg_hba.conf?

Answer (score 0):

This is the key part of your stack trace:

```
FATAL: the database system is starting up
```

It means that the PostgreSQL server is starting or restarting and not ready to accept connections yet.

You should check the PostgreSQL server log to find the cause of this unexpected start.

Chances are that it is a restart caused by a crashing PostgreSQL server process. Such crashes can be caused (in rough order of likelihood) by buggy server extensions, buggy hardware or PostgreSQL bugs.

Comment: FATAL:  the database system is starting up。LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2017-05-01 12:51:08 CST。LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress。LOG:  redo starts at 5/AB423270。FATAL:  the database system is starting up。LOG:  record with zero length at 5/AB6A4FD8。LOG:  redo done at 5/AB6A4FA8。LOG:  last completed transaction was at log time 2017-05-01 12:56:00.478503+08。FATAL:  the database system is starting up。LOG:  autovacuum launcher started。LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections。

Comment: But when this happens, still can access the database, and I try to restart the database service, and did not solve the problem, but in the restart project is resolved.

Comment: The interesting entries would be the ones *before* "database system was interrupted". If there is nothing, it was probably an operating system crash, or somebody hit the power switch, or somebody stopped the database with `kill -9`. As to the error message itself, a restart will make no difference. All you have to do is wait until PostgreSQL has recovered, then things will work as they used to.

Comment: Thank you for giving you a detailed answer. From the log did not see the specific cause of the interruption of the database, this can be found from other aspects?

Comment: Looks like PostgreSQL was interrupted (power off or `kill -9`). See how long the operating system has been up (`uptime` on Linux). Look at the operating system log if there is anything. Ask the system administrators for help.